# How to edit auto injected favicon tags inside header of a Vue Cli genereated WPA project?

Tags: html, vue.js, favicon, vue-cli

If you use `@vue/cli 4.1.1` to create a new project **with** the feature `(x) Progressive Web App (PWA) Support` **enabled**, your generated project structure looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are several icons generated, they are **automatically** injected inside the html `head`:

- Index.html:

```html
  <title>wproj</title>
</head>
```

- Rendered Index.html:

```html
  <title>wproj</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4DBA87">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="wproj">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#4DBA87">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
</head>
```

**Question:** Where are these automatically injected properties are defined? How to edit them (e.g. remove one)?

There is **no** `manifest.json` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paths are configured by [@vue/cli-plugin-pwa](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa). In the documentation you can find pwa.iconPaths in the configuration. As you can see, the default value for iconPaths is

```
{
   favicon32: 'img/icons/favicon-32x32.png',
   favicon16: 'img/icons/favicon-16x16.png',
   appleTouchIcon: 'img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png',
   maskIcon: 'img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
   msTileImage: 'img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png'
}
```

which corresponds to the files that are injected into your index.html.

The configuration can be changed with a vue.config.js file. For example this content

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    iconPaths: {
      favicon32: "TEST"
    }
  }
};
```

in the config file causes the output for favicon32 to be

```
<link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=32x32 href=/TEST>
```